# MTurk API: create HIT but submit later?

Tags: mechanicalturk

Is is possible to use the Python Boto3 API to create HITs in a way they are not immediately available to workers?

The `CreateHIT` [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateHITOperation.html) seems to talk about the HIT being available to workers immediately and I don't see a flag that let's you decide not to submit it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the API allows you do create a HIT while setting it to be inactive or inaccessible (outside of using Qualification Requirements to prevent workers from accessing it).

You could create a HIT Type using `create_hit_type()` and then later create a HIT using that HIT type (`create_hit_with_hit_type()`).